# Why do I get the error: 'PFObject' does not have a member named 'subscript'?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My code looks as follows, and it is the code I have borrowed from the quick start tutorial, at Parse.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("Object has been saved.")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I'm getting the error at the "testObject["foo"] = "bar"" line. Why is that? 
I have also set up the database key in the AppDelegate.swift file

Again, the error says the following: 'PFObject' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Comment: Clean your project and build it again because it is working fine.

Comment: I've cleaned it and build it again, and yet, I still get the error for som reason. Any other suggestions, Dharmesh?

Comment: Check this: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%27PFObject%27+does+not+have+a+member+named+%27subscript%27&oq=%27PFObject%27+does+not+have+a+member+named+%27subscript%27&aqs=chrome..69i57.536j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I've tried every suggestion, and I still can't make it work. What should I do specifically?

Comment: add a latest version of parse SDK and try.

Comment: Quickfix: use `testObject.setObject("bar", forKey: "foo")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using older version of Parse.framework.

Take a look at [Parse change log](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) and make sure you are using the latest version.

Comment: So any other suggestions, adolfosrs?